# Separate loader for each section

Tags: jquery, animation

I have a different sections like #about, #services, #products and #contact in a single page (ie) index.html.

I have a navigation list for each section (ie) for ex.

About

etc. Each section has some animation.

My question is how i use a loader for each section. (ie) For a initial index page it shows a loader, after the page loads the index section content will visible. If i click on the about link, the index section will invisible (display:none), and then the about section will (display:block) with loader.

How can we get this with jquery animation? Please find the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yesvin/GKh2s/3/

Thanks in advance. If you hav any queries please let me know.

Comment: You should really provide code and/or a jsFiddle when posting questions. I think, if I understand correctly, you're going to want to use `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` to animate the showing and hiding of elements

Comment: Hi Brian, You are right..but what i need is how i use a pre-loader for each section. I use a loader in a page. it works perfectly in starting  (ie) for index. Then i click on the about my loader will not visible, only the about content is visible.

Comment: Definitely need some code to work with. Sounds like you can just re-use the "loading" content you have on the page.

Comment: What is the "loader" you are using? Is it a plugin of some sort?

Comment: Hi Brian, Thank you for your help. Please find the following fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yesvin/GKh2s/3/ I have different sections. each section should show loader before it displays the next section. Hope you understand! Once again thanks for the help.